# Vectors in 3 space: Determine x and y if a = [x,y,1], b = [1,2,3], and a x b = [7,-5,1]

Tags: vectors

Determine $x$ and $y$ if $a = [x,y,1], b = [1,2,3]$, and $a \times b = [7,-5,1]$.

I tried multiplying the vectors by a scalar and tried solving for $x$ and $y$ but that didn't seem to get me the solution. How would I solve this?

Comment: What is your result of $a\times b$ in terms of $x,y$?

Comment: note that your "x" operation is the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: Show more detailed working rather than just describing.

Answer (score 1):

You have the result of the cross product, so it remains to actually take the cross product of the 2 vectors you have, given by - \begin{array}{ccc}
\ i & j & k \\
x & y & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3\end{array}

where i,j,k are the unit vectors. You find the determinant of this which is $(3y-2)i-(3x-1)+(2x-y)k$, which gives you the 3 vectors in the 3 directions. equate this to the given result of the cross product to find x and y. Ill give you the first one - from there it should be obvious. 
$3y-2=7$ therefore $y=3$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the cross product you have:

$a\times b=(3y-2, 1-3x, 2x-y)$.

Then set this equal to the vector $(7, -5, 1)$ and you should be able to solve for $x$ and $y$ quite easily.